# Develping with Django, Git, and Cloud Server

Tags: django, git, hosting, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working with a team in my University to put together a new webapp. Nothing too fancy, just run of the mill MySQL + Django. We are also hoping to use Git for source control. We were wondering what hosting options were available to us. We're all very competent with Unix, so a ssh connection would be preferable. We also looked into the Amazon Cloud, but are not sure if that's right for us. What does Stackoverflow suggest for a provider to host both a Git repo for us and our webapp. The simpler, the better. It should also run a Linux environment.

Comment: You should also consider if "hosting a git repo" ist enough, or if you need additionally a good issue tracker, a wiki etc... Furthermore you should include some information on the expected load of your system / why you would prefer a "cloud service"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had great success using the Rackspace Cloud servers. You get root SSH into the server, so you can set up your Git repo and your web app there. They have a lot of options for which flavor of Linux you want to use as well.

I'm doing Django/Postgres on an Ubuntu server and haven't had any problems at all. As a bonus, it includes very easy web and API integration with their CDN if you're interested in that.

I looked into a variety of cloud providers and RS had the best options for me, although CDN integration was a big deal for my site so that factor weighed heavier than it might for you.

I use the cheapo 256MB RAM/10GB HD install and pay around ~$12/month after bandwidth costs are figured into it.

Here's the pricing: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/

Comment: Ya, we currently have a DreamHost Virtual Server but we're unsatisfied with it. The stupid web panel thing won't let you just go in on the command line and do some dirty work the fast way.

Comment: @themaestro: yeah I've been on VPSes with root SSH now for a little over a year and I don't think I could go back. With virtualization there's no reason for companies not to offer it. By the way, with that Rackspace server, you get 4 virtual CPUs with seemingly infinite power. It's like having your own Cray, except with a baby hard drive :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not AWS? It has a free tier that is able to run basic Django apps well. You can run it using a [Django AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack#cloudImage) directly or a service like [BitNami Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud) (Disclaimer: I am a BitNami developer, I am actually in charge of many of the Python-based stacks). Both options allow you to run a micro instance of an Amazon Machine for free (680Mb Ram, 10Gb disk).

On BitNami Cloud Hosting, we recently added support for Python and Django (Python 2.6.5 and Django 1.3) and we already included Git. When you select to create a new server you will have access to all those components on top of Ubuntu 10.04.

Also if you are interested in using Redmine (as dgel suggests) you can select to install it when you create your server in the same machine. Since it is an university project, you may also want to consider hosting the Git part on github.com for free.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend sourcerepo.com for git and redmine hosting.  $6.95 per month for unlimited projects including redmine instances with git hooks.  You don't need to worry about setting up or maintaining the git repos or redmine instances yourself.

Then for your project's public hosting you can't beat linode.com for $19.95 per month.